# Importing additional shapefile data into R using ggplot2 and the "fortify" function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to do spatial analysis of data by U.S. congressional district in R using ggplot2.

Plotting the map of congressional districts is working fine. The shapefile is available here: http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/pub/data/nationalatlas/cgd113p010g.shp_nt00845.tar.gz

Once unpacked, here's the relevant part of the code I'm running:

```
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(maps)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)


cds13 <- readShapeSpatial("cgd113p010g.shp")
cds13.map <- fortify(cds13)


p <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), data=cds13.map, fill="white", color="light gray")
p <- p + ylim(c(25,50)) + xlim(c(-125,-65))
p
```

The geo files, however, have other useful data I'd like to add into the fortified data frame (in this case, cds13.map). See, for example, cds13$CONG_DIST (the district number) and cd13$CONG_REP (the name of the current Representative).

Is there an easy way to import such variables of interest, ideally through a call in fortify (or perhaps using merge)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONG_DIST` and `CONG_REP` are located in the slot data (`cds13@data`) of your imported shapefile. You can add those data to fortified `cds13.map` using function `merge()`. To merge both objects you should use `id` column of the `cds13.map` object and row names of the `cds13@data` object.

```
cds13.merged<-merge(cds13.map,cds13@data,by.x="id",by.y="row.names")
```